# Javascript allow special characters in textarea (Electron App)

Tags: javascript, html, electron, textarea

I am making an Electron app that has a `<textarea>`.

I am using `document.execCommand('insertText', false, text);` to insert text into the text area.

I want to insert the following string `'ⓐ'` however when I do this my text area displays the following: 'â“'.

How can I insert the special character with `document.execCommand`?

Comment: Did you checked that both of them have same `charCode` or not?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you need to use code like this

```
var spchar = string.fromCharCode(???)
document.execCommand('insertText', false, spchar );
```

and add it to textarea

please check maybe your textarea use another font that shown your character wrong

Comment: http://www.mauvecloud.net/charsets/CharCodeFinder.html

Comment: You can use `text.charCodeAt(0)` to get the character code of the first character in `text`. More [info on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/charCodeAt).

Also [fromCharCode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/fromCharCode) function is available on the `String` object.

Answer (score 0):

Inside a textarea, you need to convert the following characters into their HTML entities. This is not a limit caused by electron.

You are not specifying the server side language you're using. In PHP, the correct function would be [htmlspecialchars()](https://www.php.net/htmlspecialchars).

As of your example, we can only tell that you're using javascript, so the JS-only solution would be to replace with the equivalent entity code:

```
function escapeHtml(text) {
  return text
      .replace(/ⓐ/g, "&#9424;")
      ...
}
```

You can find the symbol's equivalent entity code here: https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+24D0